# How do I disassemble a VC++ application?

Tags: c++, resources, reverse-engineering

I believe the application has some parts that target .NET, and some that don't. I'm particularly interested in looking at the resource files, if there are any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to aku's excellent answer, for English speakers, IDA Pro is available at http://www.hex-rays.com/.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disassemble native x86/64 app use [IDA](http://www.idapro.ru), .NET exe/dll can be disassembled using Reflector. There are [tons](http://www.google.ru/search?complete=1&hl=en&newwindow=1&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=v1M&q=extract+resource+from+exe+file&btnG=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA&lr=&aq=f&oq=) of utilities to extract resources. Can you elaborate your question a bit?

Comment: Aku, thanks for the response. I'd be happy to elaborate, but I'm not sure what else to convey to help people give better answers.

Comment: Esteban, I mean there are a lot of different esource types, what resource you want to extract?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the resource files isn't really "disassembling" (not really) and if that's all you want to do you can just open the .exe or .dll inside Visual Studio or a similar tool and it will give you a resources view.

Answer (score 0):

Do not get scared by the prices, the freeware version (available from hex-rays.com) is perfectly sufficient for reversing Win32 x86 code.

Answer (score 0):

I would too highly recommend IDA for reverse engineering if you want to see the assembly code and how the binaries have been compiled/linked.

To simpley see "inside" binary files (exe, dll, sys, ...) try CFF Explorer, its free and its great:
http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php

you can examine the binary files structure in great detail including resources.

If CFF Explorer is not enough then try PE Explorer which costs a little bit:
http://www.heaventools.com/

Answer (score 0):

PE Explorer is definitely the best resource viewing tool, but you might want to have a look at its "resource-only" version - [Resource Tuner](http://www.heaventools.com/resource-tuner.htm).